# sqlserver 2012 CPU Duration variation for single clustered index seek

Tags: sql-server, performance

We are running a daily batch and see sometimes factor 20 runtime diffenencies. 
Analyzing a trace which recorded fast and slow performance timeframes I isolated a select statement returning a single row from a clustered index which logs a duration of 1101 micos (3 logical Reads) in the "fast" timeframe.
A few minutes later the same select with the same plan lasted 28'275 micros (3 logical reads).
Both timeframes (fast/slow) are in prework time and there is almost no other activity on the server.
It is a AlwaysOn cluster running SQLServer 2012 with CPU-usage always below 30% and due to lots of RAM low IO activity.
To us the trace does not reveal a reason for the long duration. Any suggestions what we could trace for to gain more insight?
Thanks
Juerg
Addition:
Added tracing for some of the action and found another strange thing. The app is requesting the same data from the same table with different PK's with dynamic SQL commands (select * from t1 where OID='...'). It does it 4 times in a row and the exec plan is the same (1 index seek and 1 Key Lookup) for all 4 selects. Each select triggeres 8 locical reads. 3 out of the 4 selects log 0 ms CPU time in the trace and 1 logs 15 ms? 
Am I right that even a physical read (can't see that in the trace but we got lots of RAM and I doubt that a physical read happens) should not increase the CPU count? What could cause that counter to be so high in comparison to the other reads?

Comment: 28ms are about 3 magnetic disk seeks. Your buffer pool might not be able to contain the working set of your work load. You aren't clearing the buffer pool or doing something else to clear or reset anything, aren't you?

Comment: Is it possible the query is sometimes blocked by, I don't know, other queries?

Comment: In the trace file I can see 3 Reads logged but it is not specified whether physical or logical reads took place. No clearing pool or other things are done, statements are all part of the same application repeating selects and inserts for each payment from a preloaded list. The machine has 512 GB RAM and all the accessed tables fit easily all into RAM.

Comment: Another fact in the 2 statements is that beside the increase in duration there is also a significant increase in the CPU counter. Would a physical read add significantly to CPU load?